# Error response from daemon: Get https://quay.io/v2/: unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, quay.io

I am trying to pull images from quay.io using my credentials.
I have Windows 10, Docker Desktop 2.2.0.5 installed on my machine.

I open my cmd and type:
`docker login quay.io`

I supply my username and password and then I get below error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://quay.io/v2/: unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

I have already tried adding quay.io as insecure registry in .docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": ["quay.io:5000"],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false
}
```

It does not work. I am unable to pull images from quay.io....
I checked, I am able to pull public images from Dockerhub.

Comment: Similar issue here a year later, in this case it's not authorization but a time out.

Answer (score 2):

You must enable `Docker CLI Password` in settings tab
Then go to the menu ‍‍‍‍`Generate Encrypted Password`
[image]